# C# GDI Snake Game

Tags: c#

How do I make the snake move in all directions continuosly without having to press the buttons always

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Rectangle rectangle;
    Size recSize;
    Point firstPoint;
    Point[,] grid;
    Graphics graphics;
    Point[] snake;
    Random rng;
    Pen pen;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        firstPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        recSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
        rectangle = new Rectangle(firstPoint, recSize);
        graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        width = rectangle.Width;
        height = rectangle.Height;
        grid = new Point[width/4, height/4];
        snake = new Point[400];
        rng = new Random();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Green));
        //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), rectangle);

    }

    private void GameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width / 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height / 4; j++)
            {
                grid[i, j] = new Point();
                grid[i, j].X = firstPoint.X + (i * 4);
                grid[i, j].Y = firstPoint.Y + (j * 4);
                graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0,0,0))), new Rectangle(grid[i, j], new Size(2, 2)));   
            }
        }

        snake[0] = new Point();
        snake[0] = grid[width /4/ 2 , height /4/ 2 ];
        graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
        graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));

    }


    private void moveSnake(KeyEventArgs e)
    {

           switch (e.KeyData)
           {
               case Keys.Up:

                       this.graphics.Clear(Color.Green);
                       snake[0].Y -= 4;
                       graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                       graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                       graphics.Flush();
                       this.Invalidate();
                       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                       // this.Refresh();
                       //moveSnake(e);


                        break;
                    case Keys.Down:
                        this.graphics.Clear(Color.Green);
                        snake[0].Y += 4;

                        graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                        graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                        this.Invalidate();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        //this.Refresh();
                        break;
                    case Keys.Left:
                        this.graphics.Clear(Color.Green);
                        snake[0].X -= 4;

                        graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                        graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                        this.Invalidate();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        //this.Refresh();
                        break;
                    case Keys.Right:
                        this.graphics.Clear(Color.Green);
                        snake[0].X += 4;

                        graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                        graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(snake[0], new Size(4, 4)));
                        this.Invalidate();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        //this.Refresh();
                        break;
                }





    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        moveSnake(e);
        this.Refresh();
    }


    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're gonna need to put a little more effort into your question. Whats wrong, what do you expect to happen and what is happening instead? Also, try to post only relevant code. You cant just paste all your code and ask us to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a `timer` on the form and for every tick move in last direction one square.

With this you can speed up the snake a higher difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `Form1_KeyDown` processing the keystroke immediately using `moveSnake`, store the keystroke value in a form level variable then process it with `moveSnake` using a timer.

Also get rid with the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)`; in the `moveSnake`